# How do I move apps from my phone to tablet?

Tags: applications, sd-card, tablet

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 Active. My daughter just got a Dragon Touch tablet for Christmas, but we don't have wifi. I want to move the games that I've downloaded on my phone for her onto her tablet. She's six years old and driving me crazy wanting some games on this tablet. I moved the apps from my phone's device storage to a mini sd card. However, when I put the sd card into the tablet it is not showing the apps. The tablet shows that the appropriate amount of space is used on the SD card, but I can't seem to figure out how to open the apps or transfer them from the sd card to the tablet. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Or am I trying to do something that just is not possible? Clearly I don't know a whole lot about technology. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your Galaxy S5 Active should be able to create a Wi-Fi network, and share its own cellular data.  This is usually referred to as "tethering", or "mobile hotspot".  The settings are different for various Android devices, and sometimes are a paid feature (or may be missing completely) depending on the carrier.

Generally, on Samsung devices like your S5 Active you can find it under Settings -> Connections -> Tethering & Wi-Fi hotspot.  You can activate and configure it there, and then use your daughter's tablet to connect to the newly created Wi-Fi and access Google Play Store, or other app stores (like Amazon, for example.)  Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jAZOWzXZjE) that shows how to find the settings.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone has a mobile hotspot then turn it on.
(If you don't don't read this)
Connect the tablet to the phoes hotspot.
Then from there you can download any game if have purchased any games see how to get them on to the tablet for free

First download ES File Explore File Manager on both devices then open it on both devices.

On your phone go to user apps.

Pick the apps you want to download on the tablet and the hit the button that says more in more hit send when you see the tablet click it on the tablet it will come up with a sigh saying download the files hit OK and they will download on your tablet

Thanks

Comment: That might not work. It, for me, doesn't work with a hotspot (I've tried), rather it needs Wi-Fi Direct connection between the devices, and both have to be paired. I suspect apps like Xender or ShareIt are a better option. Also, could you work on your spellings a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, copying applications across from one device to another is not the same as installing them. Additionally, for the sake of security Android does not allow you to run programs from your SD card by default, so even if in theory the programs didn't need a whole lot of reconfiguration for your tablet, they still wouldn't run.

The easiest and best way to get the games onto the tablet would be via the Google Play Store, but you will need wifi on the tablet for that. One way to get this would be to share your phone's internet connection with the tablet, if you have an internet connection on your phone and if your hardware and/or service provider will allow you to do so. On my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300), I go to Settings => Network Connections => More networks => Tethering and portable hotspot => Portable Wi-Fi hotspot. If you get this far on your phone, just go ahead and switch the Portable Wi-fi hotspot on with the slider, and follow the on-screen instructions to connect your daughter's tablet to the internet. (This also means going to Settings => Network Connections => Wifi on her tablet and looking for the share you just created, which by default is called AndroidAP). Then on her tablet use Google Play as normal to install the games.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to internet to download a small file, download "ShareIt" application By Lenovo from Google PlayStore on both of your devices, once you did that you can easily move all your applications, pictures, videos, etc to your new device easily!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clearer in telling what you want. If you are ok with downloading games from Playstore but don't have internet access (WiFi) you can do as Chahk said.

However this will not transfer the game from your phone to tablet.

If you specifically want to transfer apps from one device to another, there are a few options.

1. If your device is rooted, you can use backup applications like titanium backup. Then copy the backup folder to the new device and restore the apps using the same backup app.
2. Going by what you said, it seems that you have successfully copied the apk files into the sdcard. To install from sdcard you need to turn on ‘Unknown sources’ in the security setting.

To do that go to settings→ security→ unknown sources. This option must be ticked.

3. If your tablet does not show those apps, check if your phone or computer shows it. If those apps are seen in the computer, then you can install those apps from computer using adb command.

To set up adb please follow this site: http://androidforums.com/threads/tutorial-how-to-set-up-adb.603700/

Make sure adb recognizes your tablet and android debugging is turned on.

To install the apps, go to the folder where the apps are and open a command prompt or terminal (I am assuming your adb is in the environmental paths) and type

adb install *.apk

where *.apk is the name of your app.

Following methods 2 and 3 will give you a fresh install of your apps. No data will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Download an application "Zapya" ...
on both of the devices and intall it.Connect both the devices using Zapya and you will be able to send or recieve files between both of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Their is an alternative too...
Download the application "Xender".It is also easy to use.connect both the devices using Xender and you will be able to share files between the two devices.